# ComputerCraft cant access data in tables

Tags: lua, computercraft

I want to try and compare the two variables capacity and amount but I have no clue as to how to access the data. I will include screenshots from in-game.
Here is the code:

```
t=peripheral.wrap("left")
local infoTable = t.getTankInfo("west")
print(infoTable.capacity)
```

The function returns the following.

```
{
 {
  capacity = 16000,
  contents = {
    id = 0;
    amount = 0,
  },
 },
}
```

EDIT: I got it. Its a table of tables. so to access it.

```
infoTable[1].capacity
```

and for the cotents table

```
infoTable[1].contents.amount
```

http://puu.sh/gtzX9/acc0839b11.jpg
http://puu.sh/gtzZW/6b2aa52f12.jpg

Comment: Also, please include the code in the question, and not as an off-site link.

Answer (score 1):

`foo[bar]` takes whatever is in the *variable* `bar` and uses it to index `foo`. Since in your example, variable `capacity` doesn't exist, it's value is `nil`.

You want `infoTable.capacity`, which is the same as `infoTable["capacity"]`

Comment: I just tried infoTable.capacity, The program just prints a empty line.

Comment: @theindiandood Make sure the table actually has a `capacity` field. Do `for k,v in pairs(infoTable) do print(k, " ", v) end`.